# WF Security Pack Activities are not showing up in the toolbox

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, workflow-foundation-4, workflow-activity

I installed the [WF Security Pack CTP 1](http://wf.codeplex.com/releases/view/48114) and referenced the assemblies in my project, but I can't figure out why the activities aren't showing up in the toolbox. I'm using Visual Studio 2012 and .NET 4.5. Any suggestions?

I should be seeing something like this:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quote from your url:

> Please note that the Client Profile of the .NET Framework 4 is not sufficient since it does not satisfy the requirements for the Windows Identity Foundation (WIF).

So you might want to switch to the full .net 4 profile?

Another solution might be to open a workflow, right click inside the toolbox and selecting "choose items..." and selecting your activities/dlls inside the dialog.

Comment: I could have sworn that the "Choose Items..." option wasn't there, but apparently I'm blind. I was able to add them in to the toolbox and use them that way, thanks!